# jq: print only specific keys and values in order

Tags: json, sorting, unix, key, jq

Say I have the following JSON:

`{"a": 1, "b": 2", "c": 3}`

Using `jq` and maybe Unix, I want to get the following output:

```
c 3
a 1
```

Two things going - first, I am printing only two keys and values, and I am ordering in the way I want.

I know how to print keys and values, and even only some, but I can't seem to order them in the way I want (not alphabetical or algorithmic sort).

Comment: I think you mean `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}` correct?

Answer (score 6):

With your input, the filter

```
( {c}, {a} )
| to_entries[]
| "\(.key) \(.value)"
```

produces the desired output (you will probably want to use the -r command-line option).

If the ordering of keys you want is specified by an array,
$a, then you could write:

```
. as $in
| $a[]
| "\(.) \($in[.])"
```

Etc.